# How to create new columns with totals from summed values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data table in BigQuery which looks similar to this.

[image]

My desired outcome is this:

[image]

I've been experimenting with the `MAX (CASE WHEN Country = 'France' THEN 'yes' END)` as France to create columns where I can identify whether the customer made a purchase in the country, but not the number of all their purchases. Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

Try [countif](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#countif):

```
select
  customer,
  countif(Country='France') as France,
  countif(Country='UK') as UK,
  countif(Country='Ireland') as Ireland
from mytable
group by customer
```

or [pivot operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
PIVOT(COUNT(TransactionId) FOR Country IN ('France', 'UK', 'Ireland'))
```

Comment: The countif solution worked perfectly. I was unable to test the pivot operator at this time as it returned an error, saying that the field name was invalid. The real data contains spaces, so I'd need to clean this up first. Many thanks.